# Why does spacement near a div affect the position of a draggable item when dragged?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a custom JavaScript draggable for my webapp, but there is a problem with it, I added some space aroud a div called `.container_elements`, when the draggable item is moved it goes away from the mouse.

I need to keep the draggable item on the mouse position (margin around `.container_elements` may vary, I do not and won't use JQuery draggable).

To reproduce the issue, just drag the box and you'll see the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/Lindow/Xcb8d/2194/

**Html :**

```
<div style="margin-top:90px; margin-left:90px;"> 
<!-- 
adding spacement near the draggable product the issue,
(margin, padding, or even position absolute with top, left doesn't work)
-->
<div class="container_elements"> 
<div id="draggable-element">Drag me!</div>
</div>

</div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
 var selected = null, // Object of the element to be moved
    x_pos = 0, y_pos = 0, // Stores x & y coordinates of the mouse pointer
    x_elem = 0, y_elem = 0; // Stores top, left values (edge) of the element

// Will be called when user starts dragging an element
function _drag_init(elem) {
    // Store the object of the element which needs to be moved
    selected = elem;
    x_elem = x_pos - selected.offsetLeft;
    y_elem = y_pos - selected.offsetTop;
}

// Will be called when user dragging an element
function _move_elem(e) {
    x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;
    y_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientY : e.pageY;
    if (selected !== null) {
        selected.style.left = (x_pos - x_elem) + 'px';
        selected.style.top = (y_pos - y_elem) + 'px';
    }
}

// Destroy the object when we are done
function _destroy() {
    selected = null;
}

// Bind the functions...
document.getElementById('draggable-element').onmousedown = function () {
    _drag_init(this);
    return false;
};

document.onmousemove = _move_elem;
document.onmouseup = _destroy;
```

How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that offsetLeft and offsetTop doesn't account for margins of the parents so to fix your problem either set

`<div style="margin-top:90px; margin-left:90px;">`

To

`<div style="margin-top:0px; margin-left:0px;">`

or account for it here

`x_elem = x_pos - selected.offsetLeft+90;`

`y_elem = y_pos - selected.offsetTop+90;`

Comment: As I wrote the margin may vary, isn't there a way that the spacement doesn't affect the position of the draggable item ?

Comment: @Lindow so set a variable `var marginLeft = document.getElementById("someId").offsetLeft;` then instead of + 90 its + marginLeft